# Specify Taurus test as a Blazemeter Functional test

Tags: blazemeter, taurus

How do I tell Taurus that my (Postman/Newman) test is a Blazemeter *Functional* test, and not a Performance test? Below is my `bzt.yaml` I created with the help of https://gettaurus.org/docs/Postman/.

```
execution:
- executor: newman
  iterations: 1
  scenario: functional/simple

scenarios:
  functional/simple:
    script: my.postman_collection.json

reporting:
  - module: blazemeter

modules:
  blazemeter:
    request-logging-limit: 20240
    public-report: false
    report-name: my-postman-collection
    test: newmantrials
    project: test
  final-stats:
    summary-labels: true
```

I run it using the taurus Docker image:

```
docker run --rm -t -v `pwd`:/bzt-configs -v `pwd`/artifacts:/tmp/artifacts blazemeter/taurus:1.14.0 bzt.yaml -o modules.blazemeter.token="${token}"
```

When I log into the Blazemeter UI, I see that it's listed under the "Performance" tab, and looks like a performance test. I would like it to run as a Functional test to get more details on the request and response payloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it's possible at the moment, because presently BlazeMeter functional tests are geared toward either straight API functional tests or GUI (Selenium) functional tests.

The problem is that from BlazeMeter's side, the file validator is failing to correctly identify the Postman/Newman JSON file (despite the YAML file referencing it properly).  I reported this to the BlazeMeter R&D team fairly recently, so it's being looked into.

In the meantime though, I don't expect this to work in BlazeMeter.  It likely won't correctly identify your Newman script unless you run it as a Performance test for the interim.

(Sorry for the bad news on this one -- Hopefully it'll get sorted soon!)

Feel free to bring this up with BlazeMeter support at support@blazemeter.com as well.